# URL for NuGet packages in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019

Been working on another computer for several months. Recently, I did a `git pull` on another laptop which is not used very often. When I tried to build the solution, several projects failed due to missing NuGet packages.

I tried restoring the packages but this failed. Packages `MSTest.TestFramework` and `MSTest.TestAdapter` in particular were out-of-date, so I cleared the NuGet cache in `Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Clear All NuGet Cache(s)`.

But now when I right-click the project and `Manage Nuget Packages...`, no packages are displayed at all!

Back in `Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources` only a single `Machine-wide package source` is listed, namely `Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages`. This points to a location on my location disk ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages", currently an empty folder).

New sources can be added, but what URL should be used to get the latest NuGet packages?

Comment: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NuGet's documentation states that the endpoint is https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/overview-nuget-org#api-endpoint-for-nugetorg

There's also a similar question in the FAQ: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/nuget-faq#i-don-t-see-nuget-org-in-my-list-of-repositories--how-do-i-get-it-back-